# Pyspark Custom group By in DataFrame

Tags: python, group-by, pyspark, customization

I have a spark dataframe like follows:

```
s. no | address            | name | DoB
1     | st. 1 h.no 16      | X    | 1-1-2001
2     | str n.1 house 16   | Y    | 1-5-2001
3     | st. 3   h.no 1     | Z    | 1-8-2002
```

now reading the address we can se that X and Y lives in same house be somehow enter same address differently. my aim is to group by address under same address making a family dataframe.

the problem is there is no definitive column to perfrom standard groupby. i have a function to find if two addresses are same or different.

Is there a way to  utilitze that to perfrom customized group By.
final result will something like this:

```
s. no | address            | names | DoB
1     | st. 1 h.no 16      | X,Y   | 1-1-2001, 1-5-2001
3     | st. 3   h.no 1     | Z     | 1-8-2002
```

Comment: This is not a trivial problem, as you can run into the issue of connecting components. Suppose row 1 is similar to row 2 and row 2 is similar to row 3, but your function says that row 1 and row 3 are not similar? If you want a quick solution, I would say create a function to normalize your addresses so that you can do a standard groupby and collect_list. Just do some regex like change `r"str\s+"` to `"st."`, `r"h\.no\b"` to `"house"`, etc. That way you turn all similar addresses into the same string.

Comment: Good answer, but the problem is different people can enter different addresses in different format. as they see fit the only common thing is if two people tallks about same address then there is a change they mention same components of address that i can compare with the function.
so suppose i normailze one address based on street no provided and in other there can be something else

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe
.withColumn('address_unique', your_function('address'))
.groupBy('address_unique')
.agg(collect_list('names'), collect_list('DoB'))
```

UPD:

A) find similarities between addresses and put it into separate dataset: Address1, Address2.

```
adr_map = df.alias('a').join(df.alias('b'),
  on = (is_same(col('a.address'), col('b.address'))) && (col('a.s_no') > col('b.s_no')), 
  how = 'left'
).select(col('a.address').alias('a1'), col('b.address').alias(a2)).filter(col('a2').isNotNull())
```

B) join original dataset with mapping dataset and add column with "first address" that is common for all same addresses.

```
df.join(adr_map, on = col('address') == col('a2'), how='left')
.withColumn('first_address', when(col('a1').isNull(), 'address').otherwise(col('a1')))
```

C) group by first_address ...

NB: it does not cover scenario that was described in comment above.
In case if your function is not perfect enough and does not cover transitive relations, you will see different groups.

```
if A1 = A2 and A2 = A3 then A1 should be equals A3.
```

There will be some other edge cases to cover (there will be duplicated in your output), but hopefully you've got an idea and can go from it.

Comment: my function takes two params and return True/False. it didn`t work on one column